# Creating IRule in F5 based on ip_address:portnumber/servletname

Tags: weblogic11g, f5, irule

I am very new for F5-LTM configuration.Any help related to below requirement will be vary much appreciated.

I have my application on Weblogic-11g server running on managed server at port number : 8001.
   Now as my user count has increased i have created one more managed server at port number : 9001

Previously all my request were coming on http://ip_address:8001/login.html 
now still i want all request should come from same but they redirect to both http://ip_address:8001/login.html and http://ip_address:9001/login.html

Note : i would also like to inform that in my application i have many other servlet also running so i want request forwarding based on http://ip_address:port_number/servlet

Any body who know How i can achieve my above request forwarding configuration in F5-LTM.

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

> I have my application on Weblogic-11g server running on managed server
>   at port number : 8001. Now as my user count has increased i have
>   created one more managed server at port number : 9001

I don't think you need a different port and redirection.
You can still run the app on your second server on port 8001. Then you can add both the server under one virtual pool which will be under a virtual IP. Then the user can go to the app by using http://virtualIP:8001/login.html.
When a request is received by the virtual IP it can load balance the request between the two servers which are running the app on the same port 8001.

This is a good documentation in case are interested :
https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-basics-11-6-0.html